# What does Python's matplotlib figure constructor do with this number?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

The code I am currently using has the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)
```

My question is the following: What is the "1" for? I assume it is some kind of index, but the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) does not have this parameter:

> class matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=None, dpi=None, facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, linewidth=0.0, frameon=None, subplotpars=None, tight_layout=None)

Am I missing something? I am pretty sure that I am not the first one to ask this, but neither search nor "Questions that may already have your answer" gave me an answer...

Am I supposed to increase this for the next figure I plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look at the documentation of the command you're using, not some other.

[`matplotlib.pyplot.figure(num=None, figsize=None, dpi=None,...)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) has a `num` argument.

> `num` : integer or string, optional, default: none
>   If not provided, a new figure will be created, and the figure number will be incremented. The figure objects holds this number in a number attribute. If num is provided, and a figure with this id already exists, make it active, and returns a reference to it. If this figure does not exists, create it and returns it. If num is a string, the window title will be set to this figure’s num.

You don't need to use this, successive calls of `plt.figure()` will create new figures automatically.